# compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'app-home' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Ao tentar carregar meu `home.component.html` no meu `app.component.html`estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-home' is not a known element:
```

Meu `app.module.ts` e esta da seguinte forma:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

meu modulo `home.module.ts` e `home.component.ts` estão da seguinte forma:

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";


import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";


@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        HomeComponent
    ],

    imports:[
        CommonModule
    ]
})

export  class HomeModule{

}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Ao tentar realizar a seguinte ação em  `app.compoment.html`:

```html
<h1>Teste Angular</h1>
<app-home></app-home>
```

é me retornado esse erro. Alguém saberia como resolver?

Comment: Seria necessário vermos a estrutura das pastas do projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce tem que adicionar a tag exports para os componentes que vc quer que sejam visiveis para outros modulos.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";


import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";


@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        HomeComponent
    ],
   exports:[
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports:[
        CommonModule
    ]
})

export  class HomeModule{

}
```